# force rebuild of .deb

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I have been trying to make some changes to the synaptics driver for xserver. I was following instructions listed [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4v9JP2pe) to apply a patch and then rebuild the package.

This worked swimmingly. However, whenever I make further changes to the source code and again attempt to run:

```
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -us -un -nc
```

I get this output:

---

dpkg-buildpackage: source package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.7.4-0ubuntu1

dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution trusty

dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Maarten Lankhorst

dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64

dpkg-source --before-build xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-1.7.4

debian/rules build

dh build --with quilt,autoreconf,xsf --builddirectory=build/

debian/rules binary

dh binary --with quilt,autoreconf,xsf --builddirectory=build/

dpkg-genchanges  >../xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.7.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.changes

dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload

dpkg-source --after-build xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-1.7.4

dpkg-buildpackage: full upload (original source is included)

---

And then unfortunately the .deb file is not rebuilt. What am I doing wrong? How can I force a rebuild of the .deb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure to edit your debian/changelog, and increase the package's version number.
Things can get messy when you have two different packages with the exact same number.
The APT server will probably reject the second package. Also, for users of the package this might create incredible hard to debug issues, since they'll assume is the exact same software is in two different places, when in fact it isn't.

You increased the version, and you're still having the same problem?

You'll have to "re-pack" the sources with:

`dpkg-source -b <dir>`

Where  is the package source directory(i.e. the one that contains the debian/ directory).
You might have to remove the old sources, or move to another location, in which case, I would recommend making a backup, just in case.